# Какие имеются способы расшифровать blowfish в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, blowfish

Всем ку! Есть строка, зашифрованная алгоритмом blowfish, с использованием ключа и инициализирующего вектора. Шифровалось не в python, но расшифровать теперь надо в python. Ключ и вектор, само собой, сохранены. Какие есть способы, модули для python 3.5+?

Comment: [Вот здесь посмотрите.                                                                     
[1]                                                       
[1]:]                                                                                                                                                                          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042164/how-to-decrypt-using-blowfish-in-pycrypto                                                                **Я думаю это то что нужно вам.**

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, но я не могу понять, как преобразовать строки, чтобы скормить их функции decrypt. Вот что у меня:

ciphertext: wjhH1qBTHoD4oM4vkI9UzNaj3K2kCkXV%2BupPfs1hLrU%3D

key: l\x1CF\x06\xAC\x00U\xD2v\xBEiQ\xD7\xE7\x0D_\xFA|\xFE_\xD9\x11\xE9\x13\x83\xF3\x87\x86\xBF@\x84

iv: \xF6a\xD9[w\xCA\x0E@